# How to send screenshots from C# server to android client?

Tags: c#, android, sockets, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I created socket connection between Server and Android Client and sent Images as byte Array but I can't find a way to decode byte Array in android.

Every time I try `Image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);` I get errors like

> SkAndroidCodec:: NewFromStream returned null
>
> unknown bmp header format

Comment: You send an image as byte array. Ok. But what kind of image? A bitmap? Don't do that. Send a jpg or png.

Comment: The byte array should contain compressed image data. So no bitmap. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the screenshot data from in proper format? Try saving the screenshot to a file and read the raw bytes from the file and send it to the server.

Comment: I ended up converting it to a string and encoding with base64 and vice versa. It worked like a charm. Thanks for all the answers 

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your issue correctly, please try this method out.

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String jsonString) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(jsonString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    return decodedByte;
}
```

Comment: That will not help if the byte array still contains a bitmap.